# TFS Configuration - SQL Verification Error

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

TFS 2017.3 on-premise environment: 1 App Server, 1 Web Server, 1 DB Server

I'm using an existing tfs db located at sqlserver\instance and receive the following error when specifying a tfs connection db:
[image]

I updated the sql server instance to include the port number (sqlserver\instance,portnumber) but now receive the following error during verification:

TF401293: The specified SQL Server instance sqlserver\sqlinstance,portnumber is invalid. A port number and a named instance cannot be specified simultaneously. Specify one or the other.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​It appears our NSX Micro Segmentation was blocking port 1434, which is now allowed and the error no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to disable Windows Firewall or configure it as shown [here](https://elhajj.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/workaround-error-tf255049-punching-a-hole-through-windows-firewall/)?

Since the SQL Server instance is a named instance, open SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure SQL Server Browser service is enabled and is started.

Make sure SQL Server instance has protocol TCP/IP enabled.

Comment: Windows firewall is disabled on SQL Server and TFS Application Server.  SQL Server browser service is enabled and started.  SQL Server instance protocol TCP/IP is enabled.

Comment: Does TFS configuration support ",portnumber?" 

ex. sqlserver\sqlinstance,portnumber

Comment: With named instances the port is dynamic. Once you restart the SQL Server service or the computer where it is installed it will get a different port number, but you can assign the default port number 1433 using this procedure. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/823938/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-port

Comment: Changes to the protocols require a restart of the SQL Server service to take effect.